# Is it true that if $X$ is connected, then for every nonempty proper subset $A$ of $X$, we have $\mathbf{Bd} \ne \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that if $X$ is connected, then for every nonempty proper subset $A$ of $X$, we have $\mathbf{Bd} \ne \emptyset$? Does the converse hold?

I start by trying to understand what $\mathbf{Bd}$ means in "formal terms" (i.e. $\bar{A} \cap \overline{X-A}$ is the 'boundary' of $A \in X$)?

This means I'm supposed to figure out if the boundary of subset of a connected space is empty or not, right? I think that if a set is connected then it contains no partition into two sets, so there would exist points that are both in $A$ and in the complement of $A$ in $X$. This would be an informal definition of a boundary. (A boundary contains points in a set $A$ and points outside of it, right?)

What I mean is, if $X$ is connected, and $A \subset X$ is connected, then $A$ could have a boundary which means that technically, $X$ cannot be partitioned into $A$ and $A$-complement without making the boundary of $A$ an empty set.

Right?

Comment: Try to show that if $Bd(A)$ is empty then then A is open and close in the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be careful: any set with more than one element can be partitioned into two non-empty sets; a connected set cannot be partitioned into two non-empty **relatively open** sets. And in your last paragraph it’s the **closures** of $A$ and $X\setminus A$ whose disjointness makes the boundary of $A$ empty.

The easiest way to prove the result is to prove the contrapositive. Suppose that $A$ is a non-empty proper subset of a space $X$, and suppose further that $\operatorname{bdry}A=\varnothing$. As you say, $\operatorname{bdry}A=(\operatorname{cl}A)\cap\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)$, so $\operatorname{cl}A$ and $\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)$ are disjoint closed sets whose union is $X$. Each of them is therefore the complement of a closed set, so each is open. Moreover, $\operatorname{cl}A\supseteq A\ne\varnothing$ and $\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)\supseteq X\setminus A\ne\varnothing$, so $\{\operatorname{cl}A,\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)\}$ is a partition of $X$ into non-empty open sets, and $X$ therefore is not connected.

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition about their equivalence is spot on. The following conditions can be shown to be equivalent:

- $X$ is connected.
- If $A$ is a subset of $X$ that is both closed and open, then $A=\emptyset$ or $A=X$.

Observing that a subset of $X$ has empty boundary if and only if it is both closed and open, the equivalence follows immediately.

It's worth noting that any connected space with more than one point *can* be partitioned into two disjoint non-empty sets. However, it *cannot* be partitioned in this way with both sets *open* (or both sets closed, which is the same thing).

Comment: Thanks this answer is so helpful!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with your question, I'm going to address them.

First, a connected set cannot be partitioned into two **open** sets. Otherwise only singletons would be connected. Equivalently, it is connected iff its only clopen sets are the empty set and the whole space.

Second, the boundary of $A$ does not necessarily contain "points in $A$ and points not in $A$". For example, the boundary of $A = (0,1)$ is $\{0, 1\}$ and does not contain any points in $A$. If $A = [0,1]$ then every point of its boundary is in $A$.

Your last paragraph makes no sense to me, sorry.

There is an alternative definition of the boundary of $A$: it's the set $\bar A \setminus \mathring A$. This means that a point is in the boundary of $A$ if:

- It is in its closure, and
- It is not in its interior.

So now suppose $A \subset X$ is a proper nonempty subset of $X$. Assume that its boundary is empty. This means $\bar A \setminus \mathring A = \emptyset$. Therefore $\bar A = \mathring A$, and this set is also equal to $A$ because $\mathring A \subset A \subset \bar A$. But! By defintion, $\bar A$ is closed, and $\mathring A$ is open. Therefore the set $A = \bar A = \mathring A$ is clopen. This is a contradiction, because we assumed $A$ was a proper nonempty subset of $X$, and $X$ is connected.

The converse is also true. If every nonempty proper subset $A$ has nonempty boundary, then it can't be clopen, because otherwise $A = \bar A$ (closed) and $A = \mathring A$ (open), and therefore the boundary is empty. This is a contradiction.